# Layout title not showing when exporting PDF in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, layouts

I have some shapefiles with distribution (range) maps for some species of butterflies. I want to load them, give each map a title, and export each map as a PDF with the name in accordance with the title.
So far the code I have works (loads the .shp, create a .pdf with each .shp, and name the file accordingly). What is not working is the title of the map: it doesn't work but no error message is delivered. Any suggestion?

```
#load the shapefiles

repr_list = [] 

for layer in glob.glob("*.shp"):     
    repr_list.append(layer)
    print(repr_list)
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(os.path.join(outdir,layer), layer, "ogr")
    if not QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer): 
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

#define the list of layers
layerlist = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()

#define an index for repr_list (I will take the names from that list, as if I index layerlist I get TypeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object is not subscriptable)
i = 0 

for layer in layerlist:
    QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(True) #turn the layer on
    projectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
    layoutmanager = projectInstance.layoutManager()
    layout = layoutmanager.layoutByName("Butterflies") #Layout name: go Project > Layout manager > Butterflies (if it's not already present, add it) > Add new map
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
    #add map title
    map_label = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)    
    #set what the text will be
    map_label.setText(repr_list[i][:-14]) # [:-14] removes unnecessary file endings
    #add map_label to your layout
    layout.addLayoutItem(map_label)
    outname = outdir + repr_list[i][:-14]  + ".pdf"
    exporter.exportToPdf(outname, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
    QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False) #turn the layer off
    i = i + 1
```

I am using QGIS version 3.22.6 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify position and size of the label.

```
map_label.setText("foo bar")

# Position
point = QgsLayoutPoint(10, 10, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters)
map_label.attemptMove(point)

# Size
size = QgsLayoutSize(100, 20, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters)
map_label.attemptResize(size)

layout.addLayoutItem(map_label)
```

[image]

Since you use a `for` loop, you need to remove the previous label. Therefore, add `layout.removeLayoutItem(map_label)` to the end of `for` loop.

```
for layer in layerlist:

    # previous code lines   

    i = i + 1
    layout.removeLayoutItem(map_label)
```

Comment: Thanks. This shows the labels, but 1) only the 1st label is fine, then the 2nd label is added above the 1st one - is there a way to remove the label before (similar to turning the layer off)? 2) a label is created in the Object window of the Layout manager every time I run the script (so if I re-run the script, in the end, there are a lot of duplicated labels).

Comment: How many labels are there on the page? I mean how many you need. just one?

Comment: There are 14 layers, and I need only one label (that would be `repr_list[i][:-14]`) for each `layer` in `layerslist`.

Comment: Need to remove the previous label after exporting the layout.  Please check my edit.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that works. Thanks a lot!